# How to do instanceof and typecast with a generic type

Tags: java, generics

In the following code I have two methods `as_A`and `as_B`, which basically do the same, but with different types A and B. How could I merge these two methods into one parametrized method? The approach shown in `as_T` doesn't work, because generic types are erased at runtime.

```
class A {}
class B extends A {}
class C extends A {}

B as_B(A a) {
    if (a instanceof B)
        return (B) a;
    else
        return null;
}

C as_C(A a) {
    if (a instanceof C)
        return (C) a;
    else
        return null;
}

<T extends A> T as_T(A a) {
    if (a instanceof T) // compile error because of type erasure
        return (T) a;
    else
        return null;
}
```

Comment: Pass class type in your method should help to handle type issue `Class<T> classOf`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you've said it yourself, `T` is erased, and the compiler prevents `instanceof` checks involving generic types or type parameters.

Depending on how you use your `as_T` method, you may be able to call it with a class instance corresponding to `T`, without compile-time warnings:

```
<T extends A> T as_T(A a, Class<T> type) {
    if (type.isInstance(a)) 
        return type.cast(a);
    else
        return null;
}
```

So that when you need a given subclass type, you call it with:

```
C c = as_T(a, C.class);
B b = as_T(a, B.class);
```

Comment: I had the idea to pass the class as a parameter but I didn't know about `type.isInstance` and `type.cast`. Thank you very much!

Comment: Id su'ggest just looking through the Javadoc of a class you want to use. You will be surprised about how many useful and interesting methods the class `Class` offers.